# Errors while installing a Fortran 77 program

Tags: fortran, gfortran, g77

```
adwaita@adwaita-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads/netcdf-fortran-4.4.1/v2.9$ make install
f77     -c gwrdge.f 
gwrdge.inc: In function `luserd':
gwrdge.inc:32: 
         STRUCTURE /gwridge/
         1         2
Unrecognized statement name at (1) and invalid form for assignment or statement-function definition at (2)
gwrdge.inc:50: 
         END STRUCTURE
             ^
Invalid form for END statement at (^)
gwrdge.f:106: 
         RECORD /gwridge/ rdg
         1      2
Unrecognized statement name at (1) and invalid form for assignment or statement-function definition at (2)
gwrdge.inc:50: 
         END STRUCTURE
         1
gwrdge.f:107: (continued):
         REAL rt
         2
Statement at (2) invalid in context established by statement at (1)
gwrdge.f:100: 
         LOGICAL FUNCTION LUSERD(rdg)
                                 1
gwrdge.f:111: (continued):
         IF(rdg.lon .LT. lon1 .OR.
            2
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `rdg' at (2) [initially seen at (1)]
gwrdge.f:111: 
         IF(rdg.lon .LT. lon1 .OR.
               ^
Period at (^) not followed by valid keyword forming a valid binary operator; `.lon.' is not a valid binary operator
gwrdge.f:111: 
         IF(rdg.lon .LT. lon1 .OR.
                     ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `lt' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
```

Comment: i am a beginner in fortran.

Comment: `STRUCTURE` and `RECORD` are a non-standard extensions to Fortran, possibly from IBM or DEC a generation or so ago.  It looks as if `gfortran` won't have anything to do with them.  Whether or not you can persuade it to compile your code I don't know; examine the documentation.

Comment: For your next questions you should definitely add some words about what are you doing and not only the errors you get. The code would also help, although some lines can be fortunately seen in the error messages. Note your code is *not* FORTRAN 77, but a proprietary language based on Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

These DEC extensions are just now in the process of being implemented in `gfortran`. You cannot use them in the present version. See the thread https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2014-10/msg00080.html

You may try to convert the code to standard Fortran or use a different compiler. For example, the Oracle Solaris Studio supports them http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5262/aeulw/index.html.